# Handling width and height of Images and Media in/through CSS (set the height = 200% of the width)

Tags: html, css, height, width

suppose for a **Media**, which is a **Vimeo Video** the **width** is set to **100%**, but If I set auto for height than the height comes out to be **too low**.

Later, I set a height of **500px** for the **Video/Media** but is there a way so that I can set a height of 200% of the width.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/113657402" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" title="&quot;Super Sleuths&quot;" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Add your tried code here.

Comment: I have added the code, but the question or the perception of the issue will hardly change the code. Questions boil down to whether such arrangements exist in CSS or not that can help me to achive what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, `height: 56.25vw;` will maintain `16:9` Aspect Ratio

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 56.25vw;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/113657402" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" title="&quot;Super Sleuths&quot;" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vw units for the width and height of the element.
This allows to keep the element's aspect ratio according to the viewport width (Note : you can also see vh if you need to keep aspect ratio according to viewport height).

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/113657402" width="10vw" height="20vw" frameborder="0" title="&quot;Super Sleuths&quot;" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```